# EER Notation{Mandatory,Or}

Tags: sql, database

I was working on a project and found a detail that confused me very much in EER diagram. I tried to google it, but have not find the solution. Please, can somebody explain me what does the words "{mandatory, Or} " mean in this diagram?
(I cannot attach image because of low reputation) Here is the link with image:
http://c2n.me/3h0OGj3

Answer (score 0):

It means that an owner must be linked to either either BusinessOwner or PrivateOwner. It doesn't say whether it can be linked to both or only one of them.

This relationship is not enforceable in most RDBMS's. You can do MUST BE BOTH by having two non-nullable FK columns on Owner, but to have one and not the other requires a) two nullable FK columns and b) a trigger to ensure then on inserts and updates it only has one set and not the other.

I don't believe that it is standard notation, myself, but it's a long time since I studied that stuff. I haven't done an ER diagram for years.